# If $a\,d_1(x,y)\leq d_2(x,y)\leq b\,d_1(x,y)$ then Cauchy sequences in $(X,d_1)$ and $(X,d_2)$ are the same

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

How to prove that if $d_{1}$ and $d_2$ two metrics on the same set $X$ and there are positive numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $x,y\in X$

$$a\,d_1(x,y)\leq d_2(x,y)\leq b\,d_1(x,y)$$

then Cauchy sequences in $(X,d_1)$ and $(X,d_2)$ are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This was the answer to the original question before being modified. The answer to the modified question can be found in comments.**

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the metrics $$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}0, & x=y,\\ 1,& x\ne y\end{cases}$$ and $d'(x,y)=|x-y|.$ We can make $d'(x,y)$ as big as we want while $d(x,y)\le 1.$ Thus your claim is false in general. Of course, if $X$ is finite then the result holds. But for an arbitrary set $X$ it does not hold.

Comment: It doesn't say what you have posted. It says that if there exists $a,b$ satisfying the relation then any Cauchy sequence in $(X,d_1)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d_2).$ Note that it doesn't say there exists $a,b.$

Comment: Oh, sorry I think I misread the question but still I don't think I can't prove the question.

Comment: If $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d_1)$ then for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that $n,m\ge N\implies d_1(x_n,x_m)<\epsilon.$ Thus, $n,m\ge N\implies d_2(x_n,x_m)<b\epsilon.$ That is, $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d_2).$ (You can consider $\epsilon/b$ in the first case to end up with $\epsilon$.) The other case is completely similar.

Comment: So the answer is we choose a cauchy sequence in (d1,X)(d1,X) and prove it is cauchy in (d2,X)(d2,X), then we take cauchy sequence in (d2,X)(d2,X) and prove it is cauchy in (d1,X)(d1,X). But, how does this prove that they are the same?

Comment: If $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d_2)$ then for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that $n,m\ge N\implies d_2(x_n,x_m)<\epsilon.$ Thus, $n,m≥N\implies d_1(x_n,x_m)<\epsilon/a.$ That is, $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d_1)$. (You can consider $a\epsilon$ in the first case to end up with $\epsilon$.)

Answer (score 1):

One step at a time.

Suppose there exist $a,b>0$ such that for all $x,y\in X$
$$a\,d_1(x,y)\leq d_2(x,y)\leq b\,d_1(x,y)\tag{1}$$

Now let  $\{x_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d_1)$. Can you show that it is Cauchy in $(X,d_2)$ using the second inequality in (1)?

By the first inequality of (1), if $\{x_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d_2)$, then it is also Cauchy in $(X,d_2)$.